# Is it possible to set up async internet connection with DSL downlink and 3G uplink?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I've got a summer house in the woods in Belarus. It's situated 12 km away from one town and 15 km from another. 7 years ago I managed to get a landline phone there. During its installation we've put a phoneline-powered DSL extender in between, so I've got internet, but it's slow: 2-4 Mbit/s down and only 0,03 Mbit/s up.

I asked if it's possible to disable voice to make it faster, but received a negative answer.

Cellular connection is not good either, I've got two 3G carriers available there, they both have moderate to good connection (depending on weather, I guess) - because there are high trees all from all sides. Speeds are around 0,75-2 Mbit/s, but they are more stable than DSL. I live there only 3-5 days a month, there no reason to pay for unlimited slow internet, and prepaid packages are too small - 2 movies and it gets too expensive.

I wonder is it possible to set a connection in such a way that the downstream would go via DSL line, and the upstream (packet requests) via 3G? As far as I know, satellite internet works like that.

Getting static IPs is not a problem. I've got D-Link DIR-815 WiFi router with USB for 3G and a rebranded Huawei DSL modem from my ISP.

I guess some advanced routing and NAT conversion magic could solve the problem. Right?

Comment: How would the web server know where to send the replies, which in it's view should go to the 3g IP address that made the request, to the downlink IP of the DSL connection? This question intrigues me, Maybe by using a virtual machine running on AWS as a proxy to both connections using some custom traffic rules wizardry?